# Finder sidebar icons gone

Tags: finder

After a reboot caused by an empty battery, my Finder’s sidebar icons are just gone. I tried a few reboots, re-launching Finder, but I can’t fix it.

[image: Finder Sidebar]

Comment: Also happens in ElCap when switching monitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just install Mavericks and that's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting Finder by running the following Terminal command:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist && killall Finder
```

This will reset all Finder preferences back to default.

Comment: I did it and reboot, doesn't work.

Comment: It did work for me to Reset Finder Settings. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on El Capitan - terrific. Thanks!