# Finder Sidebar broken after using Quicktime Player

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra

I've lost the sidebar in Finder. It started when I was using quicktime and browsing for a save location: a lot of the icons went missing and the dropdown box only contained a question mark. Since then it's been getting progressively worse.

Now, there is no sidebar at all in Finder. I regularly get the pinwheel if I right-click the Finder icon in dock, or click the Apple icon in the menu bar. I've killed Finder, killed Dock, and completely powered off then restarted the Mac.

I tried the following solution, it did not fix Finder.
[Finder sidebar icons gone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/finder-sidebar-icons-gone)

It seems that launching Quicktime Player causes the issue. Is there a way to cause Quicktime to behave properly?

**Update 1:**
The sidebar came back after following the solution above, resetting the Mac, and selecting "Show Sidebar" in the menu. The issue then re-occurred as soon as I re-opened Quicktime Player: constant pinwheel that required force quit of QT & re-applying the solution above.

Rebooting to safe mode, rebooting to recovery mode & running first aid on the disc did not prevent the issue from re-occurring. The issue occurred when Quicktime was run in safe mode

**Update 2:** Caught in the act! When QuickTime Player is opened the sidebar items begin to vanish. When QuickTime Player is closed (and doesn't hang + remain open) the sidebar items reappear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axX63cIwbyU

**Update 3:** Launching Quicktime Player under a new user account does *not* result in Finder problems. Finder works fine when Quicktime Player is run under a newly created user account.

[image]
[image]

After fixing the issue, then re-opening Quicktime and opening a file the following screenshots reflect Finder's behaviour:

1. All sidebar items apart from network shares are missing
   [image]
2. Sidebar items appear in the Quicktime save dialogue, but icons are missing. Dropdown box for folder of save location in Quicktime is populated by a question mark.

Finder's sidebar items are still missing, apart from network shares.
[image]

3. Within Quicktime, some time after clicking a sidebar item that has a missing icon as a location to save, Finder (Quicktime?) informs that the location cannot be found. In the following screenshot the missing location is `/Macintosh HD/Applications`

[image]

macOS 10.13.6
MBP 11,3

Comment: If you [start up your Mac in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-in-safe-mode-mh21245/10.13/mac/10.13) do you still have the same issue?

Comment: @user3439894 I was able to temporarily restore Finder by force-quitting Quicktime, resetting Finder's preferences and restarting Finder, but re-launching Quicktime caused the issue to re-occur. Question updated to reflect this.

Comment: With **QuickTime Player** closed, delete the **~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX** _folder_. It will be recreated next time **QuickTime Player** starts.  Also, booting to _safe mode_, by itself, can at time fix issues for just having done so. If my system was doing this I do it just as a matter of troubleshooting.

Comment: The additional images you've added without any explanation doesn't really help much.

Comment: @user3439894 `After fixing the issue, then re-opening Quicktime and opening a file:` ...the following screenshots reflect Finder's behaviour. I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if further clarification would help. Rebooting to safe mode, rebooting to recovery mode & running first aid on the disc did not prevent the issue from re-occurring. The issue occurred when Quicktime was run in safe mode.

Comment: @user3439894 I have a crash log from QuickTime Player, would that be helpful? It's pretty long: 1.1MB, I'm not sure the best way to attach it to the question?